# Java solution for "startActivityForResult(Intent,int) in Fragment has been deprecated" when opening external URL?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My app contains a simple Fragment that is used to open external web pages, with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, externalUrl); // Uri
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open URL...");
startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, RC_OPEN_URL);
```

And, when the result is returned (in my Fragment's `onActivityResult(...)`), the Fragment is popped off the backstack.

But, I'm now getting the new deprecation warning:

> startActivityForResult(Intent,int) in Fragment has been deprecated

I've read the corresponding [Getting a result from an activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#java) documentation, but I'm not sure how to adapt the example they provide for my particular case.

I have discovered the **ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult** class, but can't figure out how to pass my `chooserIntent` to it.

All the online examples for the class seem to be in Kotlin and I've not had any joy trying to decompile them to Java. So a Java example of how to use the new **registerForActivityResult()** method to open an external URL would be much appreciated.

Comment: "I'm now getting the new deprecation warning" -- are you using some alpha version of `androidx.fragment` dependencies? `ActivityResultContracts` is still in alpha AFAIK. Also, since `ACTION_VIEW` does not return a result, there is little point in using `startActivityForResult()` with an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0-alpha06`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no reason to use `startActivityForResult()` at all for `createChooser()` - you can use `startActivity` and run your code from `onActivityResult()` immediately after you call to `startActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, externalUrl); // Uri
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open URL...");
startActivity(chooserIntent);
// Do your code from onActivityResult() here
```

However, if you really want to use the Activity Result API, then you can directly adapt the [examples in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result), replacing the example `GetContent` contract with the `StartActivityForResult` contract:

```
// Create this as a variable in your Fragment class
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    new StartActivityForResult(),
    new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
            // Do your code from onActivityResult
        }
});

private void triggerChooser(Uri externalUri) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, externalUrl); // Uri
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open URL...");
    mLauncher.launch(chooserIntent);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I was using `startActivityForResult(...)`, so I can check for `resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`. I know it's unlikely in real life, but it happens with my emulator, so like to have it covered.

Comment: When you call `startActivityForResult()` with an Intent that doesn't return a result, you'll always get the default return value - `RESULT_CANCELED` and a null `Intent`.

Comment: Oh, right. There must be some other reason I used it then, because I can see I had originally used `startActivity(...)` but abandoned it - obviously for some other reason. (Have only been using the emulator this evening, so presumed incorrect reason.) Anyway, it's all good to know! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Below answer may help to someone.... **But this is not readymade solution to above question.**

I have faced lot of issue when I try to get result **from activity to fragment**.
Finally I found below solution.

In side the **fragment**, I created ActivityResultLauncher.

```
var myActivityResultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> = registerForActivityResult<Intent, ActivityResult>(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult> {
            // ToDO: 
            if (it.resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {

            }
        }
) as ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>
```

And when I start the activity I used below code.

```
myActivityResultLauncher.launch(myIntent)
```